# Calculating the max of a field across a set of data structures

Tags: swift

I have a struct defining each data set:

```
struct TimeSeries: Codable, Hashable {
   var TradeDate: Date
   var Price: Double
}
```

and some dummy data conforming to this data type

```
var dummyData = [
TimeSeries(
TradeDate: "2021-01-01"
Price: 101.0),
TimeSeries(
TradeDate: "2021-01-02"
Price: 102.0),
TimeSeries(
TradeDate: "2021-01-03"
Price: 103.0),
TimeSeries(
TradeDate: "2021-01-04"
Price: 104.0)
]
```

in a SwiftUI View i want to calculate the max of the Prices in the Array.

```
struct ContentView: View {
   var data: [TimeSeries] = dummyData

   var body: some View {
       let maximum = data.Price.max()
       HStack {
              print(String(maximum))
       }
   }
}
```

This doesn't work. What am i doing wrong here?

I also tried to map the Price array to a new array like so

```
let pricearray = dummyData.map {$0.Price}
let pricemax = pricearray.max()
```

but that doesnt work either.

Answer (score 1):

Create a computed property for your ContentView that calculates the max price from the array

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var data: [TimeSeries] = dummyData
    var maxPrice: Double {
        data.map(\.Price).max() ?? 0.0
    }
   
    //rest of code...
}
```

Your properties should start with lowercase letters instead of uppercase so it should be `tradeDate` and `price`.

Comment: Thanks you are all very helpful to a beginner. Thank you this works.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily calculate the `TimeSeries` instance with the maximum price by using `max(by:)` function of `Array`, like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var data: [TimeSeries] = dummyData

    var body: some View {
        let maximum = data.max { $0.Price < $1.Price }
        HStack {
            Text(maximum?.TradeDate ?? "nil")
        }
    }
}
```

Other than that I suggest you to follow Swift's [API Design Guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/), that state:

> Follow case conventions. Names of types and protocols are
> UpperCamelCase. Everything else is lowerCamelCase.

Comment: Thanks. But data.max doesnt work for me. a type that contains TradeDate and Price.

Comment: @AndiAna are you getting some kind of error?

Comment: its saying cannot type check the code. try breaking it up... i think i found a way to do it is to create a function that takes in as an input an Array of Type "Double" and then filter the data for the Price array using .map {$0.Price} and pass that as the argument of that function that returns the   Array.max()! as a return.

Answer (score 0):

```
func getMax (InputArray: [Double]) -> Double {
   return InputArray.max()!
}
```

and then in the body

```
let prices = data.map {$0.Price}
let maximum = getMax(InputArray: prices)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two forms of the Array max method: `max()` and `max(by:)`.

The simple `max()` version only works if the objects in the array conform to `Comparable`

The `max(by:)` method takes a closure that compares two elements, (similar to `sorted(by:)`.

In order to find the max items in your array, you would use:

```
var body: some View {
   let maximum = data.Price.max {
       $0.Price < $1.Price
   }
   HStack {
          print(String(maximum))
   }
}
```

(Note that properties of structs should start with lower-case letters, so `Price` should be `price`.)

Comment: this won't work. unable to compile. i think its because it can't extract data.Price to execute the max method. its because data is of type [TimeSeries]. so need to extract the Price array first using map?